# How to validate username using regexp?

Tags: php, regex, validation, arabic, letters

How validate username using regexp ?

**For English letters, Numbers and spaces I am using :**

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s(?!\s)){4,14}[^\s]$/
```

How can i add arabic letters ?

Comment: Why validate a user name in the first place? What if it's a chinese name? Or a cyrillic one?

Comment: I found some examples here: http://old.nabble.com/RegEx-to-check-for-non-Latin-characters-td20509669.html

Comment: @I want only arabic and english not chinese name :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well that would depend if your characters are coming in as cp1256 or unicode.  If its unicode you can use the range such as #([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+\s*) in your expression.

Answer (score 4):

you would use unicode regexes and match all *letters*:

```
/\pL+/u
```

(one or more letters)